# I cannot center my header in the middle

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my header with ul in the center. Another page suggested having `overflow:hidden`  but when I shrink the window, a second scroll bar still appears.

Every time I try something, the `li` isn't in line with my logo. 
Also tried to have the class 'container' `margin: auto` but nothing happens.

```css
body {
  font: 15px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}


/*Global styling */

.container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/*Header*/

header {
  background: #100806;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  min-height: 75px;
  border-bottom: #ffffff 3px solid;
  text-align: center;
}

header a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
}

header li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 30px 10px 0;
  float: left;
}

header .center-logo img {
  width: 100px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

header nav span {
  float: left;
}

header nav span:first-child {
  padding-right: 50px;
  /* half the logo width */
  padding-top: 20px;
}

header nav span:last-child {
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  /* half the logo width */
}

header .highlight,
header .current a {
  color: #e8491d;
  font-weight: bold;
}

header a:hover {
  color: #666666;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <span>
          <li class="current"><a href="homePage.html"> Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html"> Photography</a></li>
        </span>
        <div class="center-logo">
          <li><img src="https://placehold.it/100x50"></li>
        </div>
        <span>
          <li><a href="services.html"> Biography</a></li>
          <li><a href="contactus.html"> Contact Us</a></li>
        </span>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Issue**

- `float` rules declared on the list-items (`li`)

Consider removing the `float` rules declared on list-items, this will negate any attempt at horizontally center aligning your menu items using typical methods other than `flex-box`.

**The Fix**

- `text-align: center` (on containing element)
- `display: inline-block` (on nested elements to center)

Since there is `text-align: center` rule *already* declared on a containing parent element (`header` in this case), **and** the list-items have already been declared as `inline-block` items, the list-item elements will center after removing the `float` rules declared on them.

**Further Concerns:**

The only direct descendant elements of an unordered (`ul`) or ordered (`ol`) list should be list-items (`li`) - any element other than this would be considered invalid markup.

**Code Snippet Demonstration:** (*view "Full Page"*)

*Summary:*

1. Markup cleaned/simplified
2. Invalid list elements removed (direct descendants)
3. Styles improved (omitting redundant rules, vertically centering
   navigation)

```css
body {
  font: 15px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

/*Global styling */

.container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/*Header*/

header {
  background: #100806;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  min-height: 75px;
  border-bottom: #ffffff 3px solid;
  text-align: center;
}

header a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
}

header li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 30px 0 0; /* remove the bottom padding */
  /* float removed */
  vertical-align: middle; /* additional */
}

/* Additional */

li.logo {
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
}

header nav > ul { /* using the "child combinator" here (>) so that this rule doesn't apply to any dropdown or sub-menus */
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

/*
header .center-logo img {
  width: 100px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

header nav span {
  float: left;
}

header nav span:first-child {
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

header nav span:last-child {
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
*/

header .highlight,
header .current a {
  color: #e8491d;
  font-weight: bold;
}

header a:hover {
  color: #666666;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="current"><a href="homePage.html"> Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html"> Photography</a></li>
      <li class="logo"><img src="https://placehold.it/100x50"></li>
      <li><a href="services.html"> Biography</a></li>
      <li><a href="contactus.html"> Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<!--

Change Log:

1) Invalid nested elements removed from list (span & div)
2) Superfluous ".container" containing element removed (as providing no tangible benefits)

-->
```

**Practical Demonstrations for Further Reference:**

1. [Horizontal Alignment (Text Elements)](https://codepen.io/UncaughtTypeError/pen/BmKMra)
2. [Horizontal Alignment (Arbitrary Elements)](https://codepen.io/UncaughtTypeError/pen/vWGbdb)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Flexbox.

```
header ul {
   display:flex
}

header li {
   flex: 1
}
```

Powerful tool flex.

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fo7v1253/1/